# How can I check the alpha of container views with the button in the bottom view of the container view-Swift 4 -IOS

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

[image]

Main.StoryBoard in this way

```
class ForgotPasswordContainerControl: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet var screenStep1: UIView?
    @IBOutlet var screenStep2: UIView?
    @IBOutlet var screenStep3: UIView?
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        self.screenStep1?.alpha = 1.0
        self.screenStep2?.alpha = 0.0
        self.screenStep3?.alpha = 0.0
    }

    @IBAction func step1ButtonClick(_ sender: UIButton) {
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5, animations: {
            self.screenStep1?.alpha = 0.0
            self.screenStep2?.alpha = 1.0
            self.screenStep3?.alpha = 0.0
            print("clicked button1 ")

        })
        print("clicked button2 ")
    }
}
```

My code is working in `viewdDidLoad`, clicking the button prints is working
 but `Alpha` does not work, how can i do?

Comment: Check your IBOutlets again. They might not be connected correctly.

Comment: Did you try other UIView functions? Are they working?